# can matlab production server improve performance

Tags: java, performance, matlab, matlab-deployment

I used matlab Builder JA to produce java codes. I saw a big increase in terms of running time.

I was told one of the options to improve is MPS (matlab production server). It is a fairly new feature and I wonder anyone has any experience with it and how much it can help matters.

thanks.

Comment: I don't have a specific answer on this, but why not ask MathWorks for a free trial of MPS to test it out yourself? Then remember to return here and report the results for all the rest of us...

Comment: @WenjieWu: you might be interested in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16140157/97160) that explains how MPS works